# Moving Notification Hub to another subsription using Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-notificationhub

I have a mobileservice on my BizSpark account, and a Notification Hub on my Ultimate subscription. I wanted to add the Notification Hub to the MobileService existing on BizSpark, I got an error and asked to try again, and it disappeared:

[image]

I tried with several new Hub as can be seen on the picture but none of them worked, gave me errors that I did not have with my old notification hub.

I then wanted to transfer the hub to the same subscription where I followed [Msdn](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/), and used the following commands in Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\johann> Import-Module Azure

PS C:\Users\johann> Login-AzureRmAccount

Environment           : AzureCloud
Account               : xxxxx@gmail.com
TenantId              : xxxxxx
SubscriptionId        : xxxxx
CurrentStorageAccount :

PS C:\Users\johann> Get-AzureRmSubscription

SubscriptionName : Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate
SubscriptionId   : xxxULTIMATExxxx
TenantId         : 
State            : 

SubscriptionName : BizSpark
SubscriptionId   : xxxBIZSPARKxxxx
TenantId         : 
State            : 

PS C:\Users\johann> $res = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceName 'MyNotificationHubsName'

PS C:\Users\johann> Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName 'DestRG' -ResourceId $res.ResourceId -DestinationSubscriptionId 'xxxBIZSPARKxxxx'
```

This gives me the following error:

> Move-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ResourceId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try
>   the command again.
>   At line:1 char:73
>   + ... inationResourceGroupName 'DestRG' -ResourceId $res.ResourceId -Destin ...
>   +                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-AzureRmResource], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.MoveAzureResourceCommand

Can anybody help me solve this issue?

**Ensure**
That the account you login with is the source subscription. Verify by comparing the SubscriptionID after login with the results from `Get-AzureRmSubscription`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following cmd:

```
Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceName **** -ResourceGroupName **** | 
        Move-AzureRMResource -DestinationResourceGroupName *** -DestinationSubscriptionId **** -Force
```

Comment: Thanks ! I talked with Microsoft Support and the above code was actually correct the issue was that Azure had not saved my notificationHub in a resourceGroup so I could not move the notificationHub but everything works now. I am however unsure of how to answer the question :)
Will probably delete it.

Comment: ok, you could leave it here for a time, it will be useful for someone who have the same issue.